# Update records in a table from views.py with Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

so basically, I wanted to know how I can change the value of a single field in Django from views.py itself without needing to use forms.py

I want to do something like this...

```
def driver_dashboard_trip_completed(request, tripId):
    trip = Trip.objects.filter(pk=tripId)
    if trip.exists():
        if trip.first().user.id == request.user.id:
            if trip.first().status == "ACTIVE":
                trip.first().status = "COMPLETED"
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Invalid access (401 - UNAUTHORIZED)")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Trip details')

    return redirect('driver_dashboard_rides')
```

But doesn't seem like it works, so is there anything that I am missing out??

This is my models.py...

```
STATUS = [
    ('UPCOMING', 'Upcoming'),
    ('ACTIVE', 'Active'),
    ('COMPLETED', 'Completed')
]

class Trip (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    departure = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    arrival = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(validators=[inthe_future])
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now().time())
    vacant_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    vehicle_used = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price_per_person = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default='UPCOMING', max_length=10)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def driver_dashboard_trip_completed(request, tripId):
    if Trip.objects.filter(pk=tripId).exists():
        first_trip = Trip.objects.get(pk=tripId)
        if first_trip.user.id == request.user.id:
            Trip.objects.filter(pk=tripId).update(status = "COMPLETED")
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Invalid access (401 - UNAUTHORIZED)")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Trip details')
```

Comment: Glad I would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the trip.

```py
def driver_dashboard_trip_completed(request, tripId):
    trip = Trip.objects.filter(pk=tripId)
    if trip.exists():
        first_trip = trip.first()
        if first_trip.user.id == request.user.id:
            if first_trip.status == "ACTIVE":
                first_trip.status = "COMPLETED"
                first_trip.save()
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Invalid access (401 - UNAUTHORIZED)")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Trip details')

    return redirect('driver_dashboard_rides')
```

Comment: Hey, i tried this method, however it didn't seem to work...